# HandlerInterceptorAdapter doesn't run for error page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception, interceptor

There is class, who extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter, with method:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
...
request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
}
```

This attribute is visible to all views, except error views :(

My ExceptionConfiguration:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver simpleMappingExceptionResolver(){
    SimpleMappingExceptionResolver r = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

    Properties mappings = new Properties();
    mappings.setProperty("DatabaseException", "error/error");

    r.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
    r.setDefaultErrorView("error/defaultError");
    return r;
}
```

Piece of my "error/error" page:

```
<h3 th:text="${user.name}" />

<p><h3 th:text="${exception.message}" /></p>
<h3>Please contact support.</h3>
```

And my exception is:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "user.name"    
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Field or property 'name' cannot be found on null
```

How can I make attribute 'user' visible to error pages too?

Thank you in advance.